# boost::ptr_vector and pointers

Tags: c++, boost, vector, ptr-vector

I would like to do something like this:

```
typedef X* X_Pointer;

boost::ptr_vector<X_Pointer> myvec;
X_Pointer x = new X();
myvec.push_back(x);
```

In that I want my objects to all be referred to by pointer so that their copy constructor is never invoked and I also want the `ptr_vector` to control memory management when the whole vector goes out of scope.

However, the compiler is complaining about the last line. I think its because i'm storing `X*` and not just `X`.

X just contains primitive types in case anybody asks.

How can I use the `ptr_vector` to store `X*`?

EDIT:

```
error : no instance of overloaded function "boost::ptr_vector<T, CloneAllocator, Allocator>::push_back [with T=X_Ptr, CloneAllocator=boost::heap_clone_allocator, Allocator=std::allocator<void *>]" matches the argument list

argument types are: (X_Ptr)

object type is: boost::ptr_vector<X_Ptr, boost::heap_clone_allocator, std::allocator<void *>>

myvec.push_back(x);

              ^
```

Comment: Thanks - I think that's one of the reasons that one shouldn't generally typedef pointers and references. You can typedef everything else, but leave the `*` or `&` explicit. That would have made this a bit easier to spot I think.

Answer (score 3):

boost::ptr_vector takes the class, not the pointer as template parameter. You should create it this way:

```
boost::ptr_vector<X> myvec;
```

Comment: Will the copy constructor get invoked because of this though?

Comment: Copy constructor of X? I don't see any reason why would it be called.